# Pointer Confusion

Tags: c, pointers

`received_data` is a *global* `char array` of length 256. It contains a string at offset `rx_pos_p` i.e. `received_data[rx_pos_p]`. I want to return the address of this string through a pointer `mem`, but I think I am making a mistake. I have written the function as follows:

```
uint8_t get_bytes(char **mem, uint8_t len){// Be watchful pointer to a pointer
        if(bytes_received() >= len){
            mem = &received_data[rx_pos_p]; //(char *)( received_data + rx_pos_p );

            return 0;
        }
        else
        return FOO;
    }
```

What should be the type of `mem` i.e. `**mem` or `*mem` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do :

```
*mem = &received_data[rx_pos_p];
```

You want to return the pointer in the pointerpointer, so you must dereference it.

Answer (score 1):

> What should be the type of mem i.e. **mem or *mem ?

Since mem is a pointer to a pointer
*mem is a pointer to a character (such as the address of the first char of an array)
**mem is a character and is equivalent to (*mem)[0]